# How to write jquery for different dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make 2 different drop downs in a page. I've wrote this bootstrap code -

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header black">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Set Point Management:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Optimized <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Manual</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Scheduled</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Optimized</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Select Operator <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'm using this jquery to change the name of dropdown with the selected component-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
</script>
```

It was working fine with one dropdown. But with 2 dropdowns, when I select any item in one dropdown, name tag changes in both dropdowns.

I tried to differentiate them by giving id, but didn't work. 
So how should I write jquery for it ?

(step wise answer would be helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{selector}:first-child` pseudo class points to the first child of the given selector within a parent element*. Since your line `$(".btn:first-child")` don't specify a parent, both .btn-elements on your page are selected. If you change that line to the following it should work:

```
$(".btn:first-child", $(this).closest("div.btn-group")).html(...)
```

The second parameter gives the element in which to search for the selector, which in this case becomes the closest div to the a-element with the btn-group class.

*To clarify, in this example both spans will be selected:

```
var span = $('span:first-child');

...

<div>
    <span>Alice</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Bob</span>
</div>
```

While in this example only Alice is selected:

```
var span = $('span:first-child');

...

<div>
    <span>Alice</span>
    <span>Bob</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you're looking for

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/6qL9w1ap/)**

code :

```
$(".dropdown-menu").each(function () {
var trigger = $(this).find("li a")
var change  = $(this).prev(".btn")
    $(trigger).click(function () {
      $(change).html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
});
```